# Populated array not giving expected results

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've done a lot of object oriented programming in Java but im pretty new to objective C.

Am I doing the following properly.

**Package.h**

```
@interface Packages : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *pictureArray;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *folderPath;
- (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)path;
-(NSArray *)getPackageItems;
-(NSString *)getFolderPath;
@end
```

**Package.m**

```
@implementation Packages

- (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)path
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSString *folderPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Objects/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], path]; //Path
        NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath  error: nil];
        self.pictureArray = [fileList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension IN %@", @"png",  @"(content BEGINSWITH %@)", @"object_"]];
    }
    for (NSString *s in self.pictureArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", s);
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSArray *)getPackageItems{
    return self.pictureArray;
}

-(NSString *)getFolderPath{
return self.folderPath;
}    
@end
```

Code in question inside the viewdidload of one of my views

```
  NSMutableArray *packages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(id key in temp){
        NSLog(@"key=%@ value=%@", key, [temp objectForKey:key]);
        Packages *tmp = [[Packages alloc] initWithPath:[temp objectForKey:key]];
        [packages addObject:tmp];

    }
```

so this for loop is iterating over a plist that I have. A series of paths.

for each path, it is creating an instance of Packages and adding it to an array of packages.

However, when do I do this

```
NSArray *something = [packages[1] getPackageItems];
```

I get an empty result back no matter what!

and even when I do this

```
NSLog(@"%@", [packages[0] getFolderPath]);
```

It prints out null.

What am I doing wrong.

**EDIT**

This is how the picture folder looks like

[image]

The code to pull it use to work when all of the pictures where in the Objects directory without any of the sub directories. I hope I edited the code properly to handle the sub dir

**Edit 2**

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.folderPath  error: &error];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", fileList , error);
```

on the line

```
NSString *folderPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Objects", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], path]; //Path
```

which successfully prints

```
2014-03-23 21:25:32.200 ScrollBar[4475:60b] (
    "object_eyes_0_0.png",
    "object_eyes_10_1.png",
    "object_eyes_10_2.png",
    "object_eyes_10_3.png",
    "object_eyes_10_4.png",
    "object_eyes_10_5.png",
    "object_eyes_10_6.png",
    "object_eyes_10_7.png",
```

When I do

```
NSString *folderPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Objects/%@/objects", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], path]; //Path
```

which outputs

```
2014-03-23 21:27:46.951 ScrollBar[4496:60b] (null), Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x8e2dda0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8e2d020 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/Users/dev/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/8B55D440-5727-471E-9BCC-1513C190740E/ScrollBar.app/Objects/object_eye_0_0/objects, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
)}
```

But as you can see in the image above, the file structure does exist.

**Solution:**

I accepted an answer even though it wasnt the real answer, it was the clear path to find out what was wrong.

The problem was that you can not have referenced folders containing sub folders using the code provided. I just many folders.

Comment: There's some context missing. Where is the line `NSArray *something = [packages[1] getPackageItems];` in relation to the code you posted that creates and populates `packages`?

Comment: Code in question inside the viewdidload of one of my views
Thats true for everything below that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `initWithPath:`, you have `NSString *folderPath =` which declare a local variable and assign some value to it. However you did not save the value so `self.folderPath` is `nil`

```
- (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)path
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.folderPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Objects/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], path];
        NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.folderPath  error: nil];
        self.pictureArray = [fileList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension IN %@", @"png",  @"(content BEGINSWITH %@)", @"object_"]];
    }
    for (NSString *s in self.pictureArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", s);
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

for logging error

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.folderPath  error: &error];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", fileList , error);
```

NEVER do `NSLog([Someclass someMethod])`, use `NSLog(@"%@", [Someclass someMethod])` instead

Comment: In other words, the OP saved the path in a local variable instead of an instance variable.

Comment: What about the array pictures are are returning empty. That one was saved correctly.

Comment: log `fileList` and `self.pictureArray`, does it have anything?

Comment: Nope. fileList is returning null when I do NSLog(@"%@", self.fileList)

Comment: what is the value of `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.folderPath  error: nil];` and log the `NSError` out value

Comment: @BryanChen, if this is how im suppose to log it `NSLog([[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:self.folderPath  error: nil]);
` then nothing prints. I've update my question to show my folder structure in case thats the issue.

Comment: 2014-03-23 20:59:49.553 ScrollBar[4237:60b] (null), Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x8f6ef00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8f6d5c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/Users/dev/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/F7E7464D-CEDF-4631-B7F6-1F27BFB98E39/ScrollBar.app/Objects/object_eye_0_0/objects/, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
)}

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy message

Comment: `The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory` I hope you understand what is this error about

Comment: I absolutely do, thats great. Now I know how to log errors. But please look at my updated (Edit 2) answer. I just dont know why its erroring out. Because the file structure is there.

Comment: goto the path you logged. check is file there. you might missed copy file build phase

Comment: Thats intresting @BryanChen. None of my sub dir are there.I even readded it. I guess I cant have sub folders.